# How to CSS the select field so that it occupy the entire cell of my table?

Tags: css

I have a select field (drop-down menu) in a table column:

```
<tr>
 <td> 
   <select id="status" name="status">
      <option value="started">started</option> 
      <option value="ongoing" selected="selected">ongoing</option> 
      <option value="denied">denied</option>
   </select> 
</td>

<td>
 ...
</td>
```

Currently, if I put it in this way, there are some extra space among the select field in the table cell. How to use CSS to style it so it end up with the select field(drop-down menu) occupy the entire cell without any extra space in the cell?

Comment: did you already try to remove all spaces between the tags?

Comment: I think the question is indeed about removing the visible line breaks (which render as spaces) from the table. You can try to float the `<select>` in the cell and assign a height to that cell?

Comment: I dont get you, what spaces between which tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking just about width, and not about height:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/aXJZP/)

**CSS:**

```
#status {
    width: 100%
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="200" style="background:#ccc">
            <select id="status" name="status">
                <option value="started">started</option>
                <option value="ongoing" selected="selected">ongoing</option>
                <option value="denied">denied</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try this ?

```
#status {
  width: 100%;
}
```